# Kullback leiber Divergence Proof

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory

Let us consider the distributions $P_1$, $P_2$, $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, then prove verify the following:

$D(P_1 P_2 || Q_1 Q_2) = D(P_1 || Q_1) + D(P_2 || Q_2)$

where $D(P_i||Q_i)$ is the divergence of $P_i$ relative to $Q_i$

Answer (score 0):

With the abuse of notation, we have
\begin{align}
&D(P_1P_2\parallel Q_1Q_2)\\
&=\sum_{P_1}\sum_{P_2}P_1P_2\log \frac{P_1P_2}{Q_1Q_2} \\
&=\sum \sum P_1P_2\left[\log\frac{P_1}{Q_1}+\log\frac{P_2}{Q_2}\right]\\
&=\sum_{P_2}P_2\sum_{P_1}P_1\log\frac{P_1}{Q_1}+\sum_{P_1}P_1\sum_{P_2}P_2\log\frac{P_2}{Q_2}\\
&=D(P_1\parallel Q_1)+D(P_2\parallel Q_2)~~~~~\square
\end{align}